# What is the scope of Network Engineering community?

Tags: support, site-scope

I keep seeing sometimes the question being marked as 'off topic' and don't get a clear reason why it is marked so.
I would like to understand what is the scope of Network Engineering community. Where is it explained? So that it helps the community as well from getting unrelated posts

Comment: SE sites each have a [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. Simply append `/help/on-topic` to the site URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First item on the help center: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

No question is ever closed on a SE site without a reason given. While there may or may not be a comment by those closing the question, the close statement always provides some sort guidance to what is wrong and at least one link to the help center.

For example, a question closed for being off topic includes this text on our site:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> "NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks in a business environment. Your question falls outside the areas our community decided are on topic. Please visit the [help center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. If you disagree with this closure, please ask on [Network Engineering Meta](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/)." – (name)
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions/), please edit the question.

Following the first help center link takes you directly to the ‘What topics can I ask about here?’ page. The second goes to the ‘What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?‘

There is specific text associated with each close reason with typical examples being provided by the second link.